# Is there a built-in way to preload accosiations for the single activerecord object (not collection)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

I need something like this:

```rb
user = current_shop.user.includes(:comments, :statistics, :messages)
```

But `#includes` method work only with AR collection. How can I preload all the needable objects without creating a separate variable for each of them (`@comments = user.comments, @messages = user.messages, etc`)?

Thanx

Comment: What is `current_shop`, what is `user`? What kind of associations are defined?

Comment: Just so you know, there is no point to doing this - preloading only helps when doing it for multiple objects

Answer (score 0):

Honestly i never tried this, but seems like what you need

Rails [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Preloader/new/class) on `preloader` class changed lately but in older api versions its was:

> Eager loads the
>   named associations for the given Active Record record(s).

Syntax should be something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new([current_shop.user], [:comments, :statistics, :messages]).run
```

Give it a try and see if it works as expected?

Answer (score -1):

No, why cant you do that. if you have `user_id` in all the associated tables, than you can simply do:

```
User.includes([:comments, :statistics, :messages])
```

you were wrongly calling the includes. if you want more models to include, you need to pass it an array.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `include` call, it accepts multiple  arguments.

Comment: Did you try your code?

`User.first.includes([:messages])`  

_User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`   ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `includes' for #<User:0x000000062a34f0>_  


  'messages' table include 'user_id' column.

Comment: sorry, I just copied from your questions. you can include in class only. I updated it now.